How to efficiently import many modules while providing a "one module index"
I have a project with the current structure:
├── program.py
└── interfaces
    ├── domain1.py
    ├── domain2.py
    └── index.py

with
interfaces/index.py:
from . import domain1
from . import domain2

interfaces/domain1.py:
import re # fast import

def print_local():
    print("This is domain1")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

interfaces/domain2.py:
import torch # slow import

def print_local():
    print("This is domain2")
                                 

and program.py:
from interfaces import index as id


def main():
    id.domain1.print_local()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() 

The reason why index.py is importing all domain*.py files and is used in program.py (versus importing domain directly in program) is to offer a one-stop import namespace that contains all domains. This is very convenient for discoverability purposes.
This follow a similar idea of what's provided by pandas for example where users generally do:
import pandas as pd
# use pd.XXX

The problem
As our real project contains tons of imports, this is very inefficient. Here program.py is importing torch while not using it and thus is quite slow:
> time python program.py  
This is domain1

real    0m0.480s
user    0m0.425s
sys     0m0.054s

while it should take 20x less time if it was not importing torch.
What I have tried
In program.py:
from interfaces import domain1 as id.domain1

=> This is not a valid syntax
from interfaces import domain1 as id_dm1

=> This solves the issue of preformance but I'm losing the one stop domain name.
I've also looked in other repo like dagster/pandas but there solution seems to load all their code.
Question
How can I offer the feature of:
from interfaces import index as id
id.domain1.print_local()

while not importing other domains in index ?
I'm also open to other paradigms to solve these kind of problematic.
I would like to avoid as much as possible to use importlib or manipulate sys.path to solve this.
The solution should use relatively standard mechanism.

Redesign your code to import their slow dependencies only when needed.
A good example of this in the standard library is in the multiprocessing package, where subodules like multiprocessing.pools (where the Pool class is defined) are not loaded by default. Rather, it gets imported only if the user calls multiprocessing.Pool, which isn't actually a class, it's a standin function. The function imports the submodule (and and of its dependencies) and then calls the real Pool, returning the result.
For your examples, it's a little tricky to demonstrate, since the code you show doesn't actually use the imports it contains (and your functions all have the same name). But you could for example, move the import statements inside the functions, so they don't happen immediately.
def print_local():
    import torch # slow import, but now it only happens if you call the function
    print("This is domain2")


Your demonstration is really clear. But let's say that I have hundreds of domain which each of them pull thousand of imports. Also some files I'm importing have slow top-level code. Putting the import in method is not going to scale very well as I will have to set this up in many places in my code.
Also, how can I identify what import takes the most time?

First, realize that imports only happen once per run of your program (even if you run the import statement several times). If you have lots of costly dependencies, you probably want to make your program long-running rather than something you start fresh over and over. There's no general solution for lazy imports, as PEP 690 which aimed to add one to Python was rejected. I think that regular profiling tools should do some amount of work on identifying the slowest parts of your code, but I don't have any specific advice on finding slow imports.

Thanks for linking PEP 690, yes this would be exactly what I'm looking for. I will look into the lazy loader library if that can help.
